# rails_admin is it allowed to show statistics count of only a model column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

In rails_admin, I have 1 model, for example `User` and I'm showing the whole user count on the Dashboard statistics.
I would also like to separately show `1` particular column from `User` on the Dashboard statistics and also able to create, update and delete them.
Is that possible? If yes, may I ask how?

Comment: I have also faced similar problem. In my case i have created a Model which is pointing to same table (users in your case). I have exposed only required fields through that model, you can create virtual attributes for that. You can then use it like other models for statistics. I am not sure if any better solution available here. I am sharing my views.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra thank you for your suggestion, I also tried the same but I wanted to show the user table. Will the configuration not override that? What was your approach?

Comment: I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new rails admin action replacing the one called dashboard.
Check out how the "controller" looks
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb

And the view
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.haml

A guide on how to create actions
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

What i would do is basically copy paste the files and add the custom column to the main loop iterating on the models.

You'll get the CSS and JS for free if you leave everything else as is.